# sql max function with extra data with it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I have the following query:

```
SELECT q.category_id as Category_id , COUNT(q.question_id) as count
from questions as q 
  INNER JOIN interestingQuestion as i using (question_id) 
group by  q.category_id
```

which are giving me the following result - just as I needed according to my data in my table:

```
Category_id    Count

     5            1
     6            3
```

Now I need to find the category_id which have the highest counter, so I did the following query:

```
SELECT t.Category_id, MAX(t.Count) 
from(
  SELECT q.category_id as Category_id , COUNT(q.question_id) as count 
  from questions as q INNER JOIN interestingQuestion as i using (question_id)
  group by q.category_id
)as t
```

and the result that i'm getting is:

```
category_id    MAX(t.count)
    5              3
```

which is a mixed up result, it's finding the max counter, but it is giving me a wrong category_id

why is it happening? and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT
  q.category_id as Category_id,
  COUNT(q.question_id) as count
FROM
  questions as q INNER JOIN interestingQuestion as i
  USING (question_id) 
GROUP BY q.category_id
ORDER BY
  COUNT(q.question_id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will order your results by COUNT in decrementing order, returning only the first row which contains the values that you need.

**EDIT**

If there are multiple rows that have the same maximum value, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  q.category_id as Category_id,
  COUNT(q.question_id) as count
FROM
  questions as q INNER JOIN interestingQuestion as i
  USING (question_id) 
GROUP BY
  q.category_id
HAVING
  COUNT(q.question_id) = (SELECT MAX(t.Count) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(q.question_id) as count 
    FROM
      questions as q INNER JOIN interestingQuestion as i
      USING (question_id)
    GROUP BY
      q.category_id) as t)
```

I'm using your query as a subquery to calculate the maximum count, and I'm returning all rows HAVING COUNT() = (the maximum returned by your query).

Comment: Tnx! this is working good, is it possible this way to return a few results (all of them with the same count which is the MAX) (without knowing how many will be)?

Comment: @ShaiZarzewski i've updated my answer, it should be okay now!

Comment: wonderful! it's working great tnx, just add "as t" at the last line before the last ')' in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT q.category_id as Category_id , COUNT(q.question_id) as count 
from questions as q INNER JOIN interestingQuestion as i using (question_id)
group by q.category_id HAVING max(count(q.question_id))
```

but you may need to do it this way.

```
SELECT t.Category_id, t.Count
from(
  SELECT q.category_id as Category_id , COUNT(q.question_id) as count 
  from questions as q INNER JOIN interestingQuestion as i using (question_id)
  group by q.category_id
)as t
order by max(t.count) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: for the first query i'm getting: #1111 - Invalid use of group function,
and for the second one i'm getting: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 t.Category_id,.."
and without the "top 1" i'm getting the row with the values 5-1

Comment: @ShaiZarzewski sorry didn't notice you were on mysql. `top 1` should be `limit 1` instead

Comment: I'm still getting the same row( 5-1) as the result